# Get the values for x and hue in seaborn barplot with nested grouping

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I created a barplot with nested grouping using `seaborn` and the `hue` keyword argument. Is it possible to get the order of the bars (and the corresponding values for `x` and `hue`) from the seaborn object itself? Something like:

> `ordering = [(1,'Group A'),(1,'Group B'),...,(8,'Group B')]`

This is my plot:

[image]

Comment: It would be a massive help for readers if you include the code you use to generate this figure.

Comment: Seaborn does not expose its objects, so the answer to that is no. But it allows to specify the order. So you can preselect the desired order, use `order` and/or `hue_order` arguments, and then you know the order in which the plot is produced.